I get `InsufficientFundsError ` when I try to estimate gas fee for token mint function
I am trying to estimate gas for the mint function in a smart contract I created.
      try {
        const gas = await publicClient.estimateContractGas({
          address: provider.token,
          abi: fiatAbi,
          functionName: 'mint',
          account,
          args: [
            `0x${p.userId}`,
            BigInt(p.settledAmount) * 10n ** BigInt(provider.decimals),
          ],
        })

Here is the minimized token contract code
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import {Initializable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import {ERC20Upgradeable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol";
...

abstract contract PepperBaseTokenV1 is
    Initializable,
    ERC20Upgradeable,
    ...
{
    ... 
    
    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    ...
    
    function _update(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 value
    ) internal virtual override(ERC20Upgradeable, ERC20PausableUpgradeable) whenNotPaused {
        require(!blockList[from], "Sender is blacklisted");
        require(!blockList[to], "Recipient is blacklisted");

        super._update(from, to, value);
    }
}

But everytime I try to mint or estimate gas I get this error.
{

  "details": "insufficient funds for transfer",

  "metaMessages": [

    "This error could arise when the account does not have enough funds to:",

    " - pay for the total gas fee,",

    " - pay for the value to send.",

    " ",

    "The cost of the transaction is calculated as `gas * gas fee + value`, where:",

    " - `gas` is the amount of gas needed for transaction to execute,",

    " - `gas fee` is the gas fee,",

    " - `value` is the amount of ether to send to the recipient."

  ],

  "shortMessage": "The total cost (gas * gas fee + value) of executing this transaction exceeds the balance of the account.",

  "version": "2.21.3",

  "name": "InsufficientFundsError"

}

I know my wallet has enough eth for gas fee. From the error it seems the code is trying to send ETH. I am not sure why that is as the mint function takes two argument, to and value.

Are you connected to a network? It could be that the contract is reverting.
